# How to get Python MYSQL connection username and password?

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda, connector

I have installed spyder with anacoda for python 3.7 version for windows. Then if I `print("hello")`, it works fine.

Now I want to connect with MYSQL database so I have installed python drivers to communicate with MYSQL. Using Anaconda Prompt I have run below command:

```
conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python
```

I got message in Anaconda Prompt that packages installed successfully. I don't know how to get username and password to connect with MYSQL? I have already checked that MYSQL installed properly using `import mysql.connector`.

Code as per below:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
def connect():
   try:
       conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                                   user='',
                                   passwd='')

       if conn.is_connected():
           print('Connected to MySQL database')

   except Error as e:
       print(e)
connect()
```

Error:

```
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python. You have to create a user account in your MySQL database and use this account's credentials for the connection. Refer to the MySQL manual for more on user accounts.

Comment: @ bruno desthuilliers can u share MYSQL tool installation url for python?

Comment: I repeat: _this has nothing to do with python_. MySQL is a totally distinct application package, the python package is only a client librarie that allow your code to talk with a MySQL server instance. FWIW, you state that "I have already checked that MYSQL installed properly using import mysql.connector" but this only means that you've correctly installed the python client lib, you still need to have a MySQL server installed, configured and running. The doc is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/ (which you could have found it by yourself googling for "mysql").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed MySQL? If you have, then there you will have username and password. Once you have them, use them in:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user=username, passwd=password,db=database_name)
```

Comment: MYSQL is not installed. can u share link?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/      and also install mysql workbench https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/    and please upvote if this answer helps you

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL has nothing to do with python this is its own rdbms, first you need to download it with other stuff including MySQL Community Server (GPL) and run the server, when you setting it up thats when you set username and password. MAKE SURE your mysql is the same as your python editor i.e. 32bit or 64bit otherwise you wont be able to establish a connection (had that problem myself). But honestly best way would be watch a youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuBcTJnIuzo

20 minutes and it explains everything pretty well

Comment: i know the mysql password  but i dont remeber the username. is it same as my local c drive user? or a different one ? if diiferent how to find it

Comment: To help clarify the question I think what Maulika is asking is how to get login credentials because when you install MySQL with anaconda you are not given an option to set up the password and username. Someone, please help since I have the same problem.